# Cannot display data from the database php

Tags: php

I am working on a php project and I have a problem printing data from the database.
The connection is working, the empty table is printed but when it comes to print the data, nothing is showed.My currently code:

```
 <?php


  $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root', 'db'); 

  $user = $_SESSION['sess_user'];


  $query=("SELECT * FROM urls WHERE owner = '".$user."'");

  $qry_result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

  $display_string = "<table>";
  $display_string .= "<tr>";
  $display_string .= "<th> Id</th>";
  $display_string .= "<th> Url</th>";
  $display_string .= "<th> Owner </th>";
  $display_string .= "<th> SharingUrls </th>";
  $display_string .= "</tr>";

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($qry_result)) {//doesn't enter in this loop
    echo 'sdf';  //?? nothing
    $display_string .= "<tr>";
      $display_string .= "<td>$row[id]</td>";
      $display_string .= "<td>$row[url]</td>";
      $display_string .= "<td>$row[owner]</td>";
      $display_string .= "<td>$row[sharingUsers]</td>";

      $display_string .= "</tr>";
  }

  $display_string .= "</table>";

  echo $display_string;


?>
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: Where is `session_start();` at your page??

Comment: **Notice :**  $_SESSION is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write `session_start()` at the top of your page to allow sessions to work on that page . Then try printing the value of `echo $user = $_SESSION['sess_user'];`

Once the value is got it should get the data from database . Alternately you can print the sql statement to check if the variable `$user` has the value.

```
echo $query=("SELECT * FROM urls WHERE owner = '".$user."'");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I wrote my solution in the first answer of the post. I gave you the correct answer because thanks to you I saw that it prints "user1" and then I realize that my owner field is different from the user and should be identically. Thanks

Comment: Yeah that's the reason i asked you to print the data .

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `session_start()`
That means your `$user` is not defined. That is the reason why there is no data fetched.

Comment: This part of php was included in another php that's why I didn't write it here, but I had the session_start() included. The problem was in my db, owner field had the values 1,etc and my user was user1, that's why it didn't print anything. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

First check if the $user value is set correctly. Then if it has any special characters you can use [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php). 
And in the table $row[id] should be $row['id']. I don't understand why you are creating a string.
You can simply add the table in your html code with something like this.

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>url</th>
        <th>owner</th>
        <th>sharingusers</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    if(isset($qry_result ) && !empty($qry_result )){
        while($row = $qry_result->fetch_assoc()){
            echo "
        <tr>
        <td>{$row['id']}</td>
        <td>{$row['url']}</td>
        <td>{$row['owner']}</td>
        <td>{$row['sharingusers']}</td>
        </tr>\n";
        }
    }
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi You have not started `session` in this page.
We have to start `session_start` at every page where we want to use session values. `Session` should be started at top of page before anything is displayed. Second please see your `$user` if it has value or not and add `mysqli_error()` to check if query has any `error`.so add this

```
$qry_result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or print_r(mysqli_error($con));
```

And please change this line

```
$display_string .= "<td>$row[id]</td>";
```

with `$display_string .= "<td>".$row['id']."</td>";`

this should be done in all other lines